# VIM column operation

Tags: vim

**Intro**

In gVim under Windows i have to replace insert and mod in each string of file some character in a specifics position.

**Example**

```
QWAER;PA 0X000055;123WAAAA
TYUIO;PA 0Y000056;123VAAAA
```

need to  become

```
QWAE@;PAX000055;123;WAAAA
TYUI@;PAY000056;123;VAAAA
```

modify char 5 in @
delete char 9,10
insert ; in original pos 22 or after delete in pos 20

**More Info**

Usually I do

Put cursor and beginning of text to select
Press CTRL-V (CTRL-Q in gVim) to begin select of the column
keep press SHIFT and selecte the interested area
the go at the end of file
then do the replace insert or modification.
(This is where I learn about [Keyboard-only column block selection in GVim Win32, or why does Ctrl-Q not emulate Ctrl-V when mswin.vim is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163642/keyboard-only-column-block-selection-in-gvim-win32-or-why-does-ctrl-q-not-emula)
and here i learn how to do the insert(http://pivotallabs.com/column-edit-mode-in-vi/)

It's not a correct way to do the things.

In vim i can do the replaceof a fange of rows, and so on using commands.

I think that should be possible to use commands to replace a portion of each string but i have no Knoledge about those command.

this is the main idea

[Replacing alternate line in vi text file with a particular string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680552/replacing-alternate-line-in-vi-text-file-with-a-particular-string)

**Question**

Is there a way to do the operations using commands with absolute position and not selection.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:{range}normal 5|r@9|2x20|i;
```

Does what you want on the lines covered by `{range}`:

```
5|r@    " go to column 5 and replace the character with @
9|2x    " go to column 9 and cut 2 characters
20|i;   " go to column 20 and insert a ; to the right
```

So…

- `:5,25norm 5|r@9|2x20|i;` would apply that transformation to lines 5 to 25,
- `:.,$norm 5|r@9|2x20|i;` would apply that transformation from the current line to the last,
- `:'<,'>norm 5|r@9|2x20|i;` would apply that transformation to the current (or last) visual selection,
- `:'{,'}norm 5|r@9|2x20|i;` would apply that transformation to the current "paragraph",
- `:%norm 5|r@9|2x20|i;` would apply that transformation to the whole buffer,
- and so on…

You could also record it, let's say in register `q`:

```
qq
5|r@
9|2x
20|i;<Esc>
q
```

and play it back on `{range}`:

```
:{range}@q
```

Or spend 30 minutes trying to come up with the right `:s//` command…

---

Reference:

```
:help range
:help :normal
:help |
:help r
:help x
:help i
:h recording
```